# Transitioning content using css

Tags: html, css

I want to change the content of a div and dont want it to be immediate. I want the text to come in slowly on hover.

**NOTE:WANT A PURE CSS SOLUTION**

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div:after {
    content:"positive!";
    transition:content 2s;
}
div:hover:after {
    content:"negative!";
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6NGrj/225/)

Comment: The `content` property can't be animated like that. Here is a [good list of animated properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) that you can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `:before` and `:after`, like:

```
div:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content:"positive!";
    opacity: 1;
    transition:2s;
}
div:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content:"negative!";
    opacity: 0;
    transition:2s;
}
div:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
div:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/6NGrj/226/)